# google ReCaptcha во время парсинга данных

Tags: php, c#, парсер, recaptcha

Делаю инструмент для удобства работы с неким сторонним сайтом, на одном из этапов столкнулся с проблемой, при авторизации через `CURL`, на стороннем сайте, иногда вылазит `google reCaptcha`. Основная проблема - оно привязана к домену сайта и когда я ее вывожу себе в окно что бы решить, получаю ошибку, к примеру:

> localhost не является доверенным доменном.

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть ли способ вывести себе в ПО(`C# winforms, asp.net` например) или в браузер, если `php`, подобного рода капчу для ее решения. На крайний случай рассматриваю вариант сервисов по решению капчи.
Уточнение, я не ищу/прошу готового решения, прошу человека имеющего подобный опыт, дать мне "ниточку" или совет.
Пока функционал не большой и написан на php, так же работаю с C#, ввиду чего указал и то и другое в метках. На чем писать не принципиально, главное решение.

Comment: А что вы выводите к себе в окно ? как получаете картинку ? ведь там шифрованный ключ который подставляется в сессию. Домен здесь не играет никакой роли, так как запрос на сервер google делает ваш браузер с вашего ип, при чём здесь домен ?

Answer (score -1):

Вам нужно два параметра адрес скрипта, и адрес картинки.

1. **Адрес скрипта с вашим ключём "k=" на сервере Google**

ключ k расположен в исходном коде сайта начиная с **/recaptcha/api/noscript?k=**

Адрес запроса скрипта **http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/noscript?k= + k.value**

2. **Адрес картинки на сервере Google "c="**

Получив тело документа извлекаем ключ для URL картинки "c="

ключ расположен начиная с **src="image?c= "**

Адрес картинки **http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/image?c= + c.value**

Думаю описывать как делать запросы к серверу не нужно, ибо это уже другая тема.

Comment: Спасибо. Этот способ сработает если капча не привязана к домену, на котором она открывается или я чего не понимаю? То есть спарсив капчу и открыв ее на localhost разве она не смотри где ее открывают?

Comment: @Winteriscoming На каком localhos ? вы получаете бинарное изображение - отрывайте хоть в обозревателе изображений виндовс, при чём здесь домен? для домена генерируется ключ `k` который вы парсите на этом участь домена закончена.

Comment: Я распрасиваю страницу авторизации на сайте и если там отображен блок с капчей, вывожу ее себе на страницу для того что бы ее решить, и в дальнейшем отправить решенный ключ-ответ на сервер вместе с логином и паролем. При попытках отобразить капчу для ее решения она ругается на недопустимый домен. Чуть позже прикреплю скрин. А что предложили вы?

Comment: @Winteriscoming  я даже не знаю продолжать ли вам пояснять, возможно вам необходимо набраться опыта в базовых аспектах, прежде чем их использовать в комплексе. И всё-же, вы делаете `Get` запрос на сайт с капчей, парсите ключ `k`, подставляете ключ в url , делаете `Get` на сервер google, парсите ключ `c` подставляете ключ в URL - скачиваете картинку, отправляете "POST" со всеми аргументами - вуаля !  ВАЖНО сохранение сессий !!!